# Get BTC prices on Google Sheets from Google Finance

Tags: google-sheets, bitcoin, google-finance

I'm trying to get data from Google Finance in Google Sheets with this formula:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:BTC")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE, the query for the symbol: 'CURRENCY:BTC' returned no data.
```

Although on Google Finance itself, I can get BTC prices:

```
https://www.google.com/finance?q=CURRENCY:BTC
```

with the same query strings.

How can I can fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have a from and to currency like this:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC")
```

For historic close price use:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC","close","07/07/2017")
```

If you want only the price returned use:

```
=iferror(index(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC","close","07/07/2017"),2,2))
```

Comment: This doesn't work with other parameters of the function (e.g. close prices, for 7 days ago). How can I do this?

Comment: @Filipe Ferminiano See addition to answer.

Comment: This stopped working today. Getting parameter 1 value is invalid.

Comment: "date is a text and cannot be coerced to a number"

Comment: =GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC") or =GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:BTCUSD")  does NOT return correct value anymore! only =GoogleFinance("BTCUSD") does !

Answer (score 14):

As of 2020-08-15 the following formula works well (without any add-ons):

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BTCUSD")
```

Seems like it works only for BTC and ETH though.

Comment: Where is the full list of currencies?
Solana (SOLUSD) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

**2022-05-04**, the following works on Google Sheets:

**=googlefinance("CURRENCY:USDBTC")** as well as most combinations of currency and BTC (and ETH, LTC, BNB, XRP, XLM, and ADA), for example GBPBTC and JPYBTC.

**=googlefinance("CURRENCY:BTCUSD")** works too, in the same combinations of coin and currency.

Although finance.google.com has DOGE and LINK pricing, they don't seem to work the same way in the Sheet's googlefinance function.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to work with crypto currency is to use the add-on where you can extract data from other sources.

```
=CRYPTOFINANCE("BTCUSD")
```

Link below:

- https://jbuty.com/how-to-get-crypto-currencies-rates-and-more-in-google-sheet-1a57e571bc14

Comment: this is buggy , doesn't work quite well with historic dates, dev said it's working on

Comment: The permissions required to access this formula, look super sketchy.